# OpenCV : convert the pointer in memory to image

Tags: c++, c, image, pointers, opencv

I have a grabber which can get the images and show them on the screen with the following code

```
while((lastPicNr = Fg_getLastPicNumberBlockingEx(fg,lastPicNr+1,0,10,_memoryAllc))<200) {                                                           
                iPtr=(unsigned char*)Fg_getImagePtrEx(fg,lastPicNr,0,_memoryAllc);                  
                ::DrawBuffer(nId,iPtr,lastPicNr,"testing");                                         }
```

but I want to use the pointer to the image data and display them with OpenCV, cause I need to do the processing on the pixels. my camera is a CCD mono camera and the depth of the pixels is 8bits. I am new to OpenCV, is there any option in opencv that can get the return of the (unsigned char*)Fg_getImagePtrEx(fg,lastPicNr,0,_memoryAllc); and disply it on the screen? or get the data from the iPtr pointer an allow me to use the image data?

Comment: Is your Camera not supported or why are you trying to mess with pointers?

Comment: hi bamboon, im not sure about this, does it mean that if it supports my camera then I dont need to use the framegrabber interface, and I can use the OpenCV directly to get the images?

Comment: Thank you so much. Im going to try it now.

Comment: im trying to use the sample from this link : http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture but it keep giving me this message : Error:capture is NULL, do you know how can I find out if the opencv is supporting my camera. ??

Comment: there is a list here which I assume is probably not complete though. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FullOpenCVWiki#Welcome.2FOS.OS_Specific_Stuff

Comment: I am using Mikrotron CMOS High Speed Camera - Eosens (MC1362) , which it wasnt in that list.

Comment: @bamboon my good old crystal ball never fails to surprise me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating an `IplImage` from `unsigned char* raw_data` takes 2 important instructions: [`cvCreateImageHeader()`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvsetdata#IplImage*%20cvCreateImageHeader%28CvSize%20size,%20int%20depth,%20int%20channels%29) and  [`cvSetData()`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvsetdata#void%20cvSetData%28CvArr*%20arr,%20void*%20data,%20int%20step%29):

```
// 1 channel for mono camera, and for RGB would be 3
int channels = 1; 
IplImage* cv_image = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(width,height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, channels);
if (!cv_image)
{
    // print error, failed to allocate image!
}

cvSetData(cv_image, raw_data, cv_image->widthStep);

cvNamedWindow("win1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("win1", cv_image);
cvWaitKey(10);

// release resources
cvReleaseImageHeader(&cv_image);
cvDestroyWindow("win1");
```

I haven't tested the code, but the roadmap for the code you are looking for is there.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your code, Im trying your code, its doeant show any error, but on the screen it only shows a gray image and quickly close the window. do you know why it doesnt show my images?

Comment: Try changing the time in `cvWaitKey()`. It's the amount of miliseconds it will wait for a key press. I think you can try passing `0` to force the function to wait for a keypress. Also, do you mean that it shows your image in gray shades , or just a full gray rectangle inside the window? Are your images colored?!?

Comment: Thank you. well my camera is a monochrome camera. but the image is only a full gray rectangle. one more question, I put the whole code in the while LOOP except ReleaseImageHeader and the DestroyWinodw. hope this is correct

Comment: In that case, leave the `cvNamedWindow()` call out of the loop. Else it will create a new window on every iteration and this can cause problems, including the one you are seeing.

Comment: WOW, you are STAR, it did work and its showing the images from the memory. one more question as I am new to openCV, I was trying to use the openCV directly without a need of using the framegrabber, I am using Mikrotron CMOS High Speed Camera - Eosens (MC1362) camera, but none of the simple examples, work, do you have any Idea how can I use OpenCV connected to camera?

Comment: Thanks, you can click on the checkbox near my answer to select it as the official answer to your question. If your camera is not on [this list](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS) then you are already doing the way it should be done.

Comment: Just a heads up, since we ran into issues with this example in our robotics project - `cv_image->widthStep` is an aligned row size (look it up in OpenCV documentation) while `cvSetData` expects actual row size, so in some cases where the aligned value does not match the actual row size, you'll get your pixels shifted.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++, I don't understand why your are not doing it the simple way like this:

If your camera is supported, I would do it this way:

```
   cv::VideoCapture capture(0);

   if(!capture.isOpened()) {
     // print error
     return -1;
   }

   cv::namedWindow("viewer");

   cv::Mat frame;

   while( true )
   {
     capture >> frame;

     // ... processing here

     cv::imshow("viewer", frame);
     int c = cv::waitKey(10);
     if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; } // press c to quit
   }
```

I would recommend starting to read the docs and tutorials which you can find [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/index.html).

Comment: Simple: the OP might not be reading a file from the disk. It seems he is grabbing the frames directly from a device.

Comment: @karlphillip why isn't he using the proper way then? I simply assume the problem is of a total different nature.

Comment: Maybe his device is not supported? ;)

Comment: @karlphillip sounds reasonable, we'll have to ask him that.

Comment: hi all, thank you so much for contributing to solve my problem. as I told you I am new to OpenCV, and Im not sure of it supports my camera or not.  the only thing that I understand is that I have a framegrabber, and I'm using the framegrabber interface to get the data from camera and store them in the memory, now instead of using the grabber interface, which doesnt give me that much options for image processing I need to read the raw data from the memory by OpenCV then I can prepare them for processing