# Convert SDL_Surface to IplImage

Tags: opencv, sdl

I converted **IplImage** to **SDL_Surface**
With the reference of this [***link***](http://s114.codeinspot.com/q/394190)

```
SDL_Surface *single_channel_ipl_to_surface (IplImage *opencvimg)
{
    SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom((void*)opencvimg->imageData,
                           opencvimg->width,
                           opencvimg->height,
                           opencvimg->depth*opencvimg->nChannels,
                           opencvimg->widthStep,
                           1, 1, 1 ,0);
    return surface;
}
```

How can I convert **SDL_Surface** to **IplImage**

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 pieces of information you'll have to retrieve from SDL_Surface, so investigate the API to know how you can retrieve:

- The **size** of the image (width/height);
- The **bit depth** of the image;
- The **number of channels**;
- And the **data** (pixels) of the image;

After that you can [create an IplImage from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124717/opencv-convert-the-pointer-in-memory-to-image/10125322#10125322) with `cvCreateImageHeader()` followed by `cvSetData()`.

Comment: Let me try (its gonna take me time) and then revert back...Thanks for the answer by the way...